# How can I create a Mouse Enter event on a specific UserControl(Index)?

Tags: c#, winforms, events, indexing

Example picture: [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ngaxg.png]

Hey guys, so I have alot of user controls created as seen in the picture posted here. I want to check which user control was the user put his mouse on, to create that little white border. I have a list that holds every UserControl instance. How can I create that event?
Code from my form painting(where I'm creating the white border):
Where list_c is my usercontrol holder list.

```
foreach (UserControl1 user in list_c)
{
   ControlPaint.DrawBorder(e.Graphics, user.ClientRectangle, 
      Color.White, ButtonBorderStyle.Solid);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the mouse enter and mouse leave event of UserControl. On mouse enter, draw border. On mouse leave, remove the border.

Comment: That's what I did, I created a bool variable that goes true when the user enters the mouse on the control and false and it leaves. It still won't work

Comment: Please make sure that you are calling Invalidate() after setting the Boolean variable in both mouse enter and mouse leave overridden methods.